# Python MySQL Connector Printing Results

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to retrieve data from a mysql server using the Python MySQL Connector.

So far, I have the query set up right using example code I found, and other resources. The problem is, I'm not sure how get it to print back all the rows, instead of just a certain row.

The code I'm using is:

```
def dbConnect(tag):
    qrfid = tag
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', host='localhost', database='test')
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

    query = ("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `rfid`= %s")


    cursor.execute(query, (qrfid,))

    if not cursor.rowcount:
        print("No results found")
    else:
        for row in cursor:
            print row[1]

    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

I'm using a test table that has only 3 columns in it: id, name, and rfid.

The above code only prints out the 2nd column, name, where if I put row[0], I get id, etc.

I'm use to using PHP for queries, but the RFID readers I'm using only have Python, Flash, and C support. Python is the language I know the most out of those 3.

Thanks!

Comment: If im not mistaken just do "select * from `user`" without the where clause...

Comment: @sbrichards - Although that would work, I want to query based off of the RFID value, qrfid. Just selecting all from user would give me everything from the user table. I just want everything from a certain user where rfid is their rfid number.

Answer (score 1):

Morning Trevor,

it is a bit late, but your question seems to be unanswered and should not stay like this.

I guess you've mistaken the way the data is returned. You assumed that you access the data of the header using row[0] and the records using row[1], row[2] ...
But actually, the "for row in cursor:" statement creates an iterator for the cursor object, which returns one complete record per loop. The record is represented in form of a tuple, referenced by name row. You can display the while record using "print(record)" or slice out the first column with row[0], second with row[1], etc.

So, everything seems fine. However, be careful with the query where clause. When comparing to a string (%s placeholder), you should always enclose the string in quotes. Some SQL interpreters expect string literals in comparisons to be quoted.